# cmd -> pip -> "O sistema não pode executar o programa especificado."

Tags: python, pip, pygame, python-kivy

Gente como resolver isso? windows 10- 64bits e o Python 3.6.5 (64-bit)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]